# how to make complete crud with google sheet and android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i want to delete and update a row in google sheet by android studio app please can someone help me with it, i do know how to insert and read at the moment but i still dont have any idea about update and delete so please can any help me with it, thanks in advance.

here is my code

android part:

```
public class ListItem extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    ListView listView;
    SimpleAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog loading;
    EditText editTextSearchItem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_item);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_items);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        editTextSearchItem = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.search);

        getItems();
    }

    private void getItems(){
        loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Loading", "Please wait",false,true);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,"script link",

                new Response.Listener<String>(){
            @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                parseItems(response);
            }
            },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        int socketTimeOut = 50000;
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeOut,0,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queue.add(stringRequest);
                }


                private void parseItems(String jasonResposnce){
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jasonResposnce);
                        JSONArray jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("items");

                        for (int i = 0; 1 < jarray.length(); i++){

                            JSONObject jo = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String itemName = jo.getString("itemName");
                            String brand = jo.getString("brand");
                            String price = jo.getString("price");
                            String itemId = jo.getString("itemId");


                            HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();
                            item.put("itemName",itemName);
                            item.put("brand",brand);
                            item.put("price",price);
                            item.put("itemId",itemId);


                            list.add(0,item);

                        }
                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,list,R.layout.list_item_row,
                            new String[]{"itemName","brand","price","itemId"},new int[]{R.id.name,R.id.brand,R.id.price,R.id.itemId});

                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    loading.dismiss();

                    editTextSearchItem.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                            ListItem.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                        }
                    });
    }


    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ItemDetails.class);
        HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
        String itemName = map.get("itemName").toString();
        String brand = map.get("brand").toString();
        String price = map.get("price").toString();
        String itemId = map.get("itemId").toString();


        intent.putExtra("itemName", itemName);
        intent.putExtra("brand", brand);
        intent.putExtra("price", price);
        intent.putExtra("itemId", itemId);

        startActivity(intent);
    }


}










public class ItemDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tvitemId,tvitemName,tvBrand,tvPrice;
    Button btnUpdate,btnDelete;
    String itemId,itemName,brand,price;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle saveedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(saveedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.item_details);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        itemId = intent.getStringExtra("itemId");
        itemName = intent.getStringExtra("itemName");
        brand = intent.getStringExtra("brand");
        price = intent.getStringExtra("price");

        tvitemId = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.itemId);
        tvitemName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.itemName);
        tvBrand = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.brand);
        tvPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.price);
        btnUpdate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_edit);
        btnDelete = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);

        tvitemId.setText(itemId);
        tvitemName.setText(itemName);
        tvBrand.setText(brand);
        tvPrice.setText(price);


            }





        }
```

google script part:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("google sheet link");

var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('sheetname');


function doPost(e){
  var action = e.parameter.action;

  if(action == 'addItem'){
    return addItem(e);
  
   }
}


function doGet(e){

  var action = e.parameter.action;

  if(action == 'getItems'){
    return getItem(e);
  }
}





function addItem(e){
  var date = new Date();
  var itemId = sheet.getLastRow(); //Item1
  var itemName = e.parameter.itemName;
  var brand = e.parameter.brand;
  var price = e.parameter.price;
  
  sheet.appendRow([date,itemId,itemName,brand,price]);

  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.Text);


}



function getItem(e){

  var records={};

  var rows = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()  -  1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  data = [];

  for (var r = 0, l=rows.length; r < l; r++) {
    var row = rows[r],
    record = {};
    record['itemId'] = row[1];
    record['itemName'] = row[2];
    record['brand'] = row[3];
    record['price'] = row[4];

    data.push(record);
  }
  records.items = data;
  var result=JSON.stringify(records);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating and deleting will require you to know some information about the data you want to update/delete.

You could do this by storing a unique ID along with each entry that you store... however this will then require iterating every row in your spreadsheet, finding the one that matches the ID, and then either [updating the values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) of that row or [clearing it altogether](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)).

To avoid using an ID you could search for a complete match on what you are looking for, such as checking it matches `itemName`, `brand` and `price`.

However this approach is definitely not recommended, and Google Sheets is not intended to be used as a database, and I highly recommend you move across to an actual database.

[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) is free and includes two different type of very easy to use noSQL databases.

Comment: thank you for your response i do have an id assigned to each row by google script not manually can you check the code for me if its possible to do, and i will try firebase if google sheet didnt work.

Comment: A problem with this is that you need to know the ID when making a call to apps script. You could use another database to store this ID, so you know what to look for in Apps Script... but then why not just use that database for everything. Also, as your spreadsheet grows, you will need to search through every single row, every single time. It will be very slow, and resource intensive. This is exactly what databases do well.